# Using powershell as default interpreter on Windows 10's SSHD?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, sshd, powershell-3.0

When using the default Windows 10 `sshd` (SSH serv[er|ice] / daemon), how does one set it to login with `powershell` instead of `cmd`?

Comment: On this install I am running 1703 and `cmd.exe` is still the default shell. Perhaps it's because this was originally using the previous version when it was setup initially?

Comment: Hmm, well a search like `switch to powershell for default sshd shell` doesn't yield anything (0 results) for switching to powershell for sshd, so I guess I'm not finding the search results you're seeing.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding my question here. I'm talking about the sshd default shell. What you're referring to is only the default shell in 1703 (and yes, it is set to default already in there, but NOT in the sshd config (ssh server), e.g. https://ctrl.blog/entry/how-to-win10-ssh-service

Comment: No, `sshd` is "SSH Daemon" as per the *nix parlance. Since we're using `ssh` and `sshd` in Windows now since MS has included it as per the last couple 10 updates, and they forked the official sshd implementation, then it's appropriate to stick with that parlance.  One might want to call it a `SSH Service`, but sticking with `d` would still be more colloquially acceptable.  I'm **not** referring to the SSD-HDD HYBRID drives obviously. :D

Comment: Yes; I realize that now.  Might clarify your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Intro

OpenSSH server and client implementation for Windows platform had been in active development in 2017 which is why configuration, directory names etc. have been changing.  Please inspect [official repository of OpenSSH for Windows](https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable) for the latest information.

#### Answer

Edit the `sshd_config` file located at `%ProgramData%\ssh`:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
Subsystem powershell c:/pwsh/pwsh.exe -sshs -NoLogo -NoProfile
```

> Due to the [bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/784) directories with space in the name are not correctly processed in sshd configuration, that is why you should create symbolic link to Powershell directory: `mklink /D c:\pwsh "C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6"`

Restart sshd service:

```
Restart-Service sshd
```

You are done.

> Full information can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-6)

Answer (score 4):

On Windows 10 Pro as of this writing, the default shell is read from the Windows Registry.

Here's how you may modify it:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -PropertyType String -Force
```

Source:

> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration